# How To Find Product Title title.phtml?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

This file path is listed for the product title on the product details page when I turn on the developer hints:
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml

But there is no file under vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank....

How do you find the phtml file without doing a folder & sub-folder search for every file you want to locate?

Comment: developer hints point module-theme not theme-frontend-blank, you can search in vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you find the phtml file without doing a folder & sub-folder
>   search

You can identify the file by many ways.

1. Your file location will be `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml. unless it is overrided by any theme.`
2. We have a grep command (using in ubuntu) to identify the string files list in a specific folder
   `grep -i -n -r "Mytitle or My string" /var/www/magento/your related folder you want to grep`
3. Magento Layouts are more helpful to identify the files like phtml path and blocks or by child block names. `/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Check your theme if you are not using default.

Hope this helps.